# autosize text in EditText and TextView android

Tags: android, text, textview, android-edittext, autosize

I hope  my English is not too bad.
I spent a whole day looking for the solution and now I want to share with you:

```
for (int i=3;i<500;i++){

    String finalVal ="0"; //I used a number but is the same for chart
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setTextSize(i);
    paint.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF); //if you use a particular font
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    Rect result = new Rect();
    paint.getTextBounds(finalVal, 0, finalVal.length(), result);

    Resources r = getResources();
    float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, result.height(), r.getDisplayMetrics());

    if (px>et_no_perc.getHeight()){
       EditText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX ,i-1);
    break;      
    }
}
```

I hope it can be useful!

Answer (score -1):

Autosizing texts in `TextView` and in `EditText` is now standard in Android 8.0 (API level 26). Look at the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview.html).

Answer (score -2):

```
        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/send_message_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:hint="@string/type_text_message"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"

        android:maxLines="10"
        android:minLines="1"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:gravity="top|left"
         android:layout_weight="1"
       />
```

Comment: It would be helpful to add some comments or explain your answer instead of just posting the code.